# Is there any way to pass dynamic parameter with route attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on CMS and need to do dynamic routing. I tried a lot of things but I decided to use routing like below.

```
[Route("{leftPath:values(announcements|duyurular)}/{announceUrl?}")]
public ActionResult Announcements(string leftPath, string announceUrl)
{
    ViewBag.Url = announceUrl;
    return View();
}
```

**Problem:**

> [Route("{leftPath:values(**announcements|duyurular**)}/{announceUrl?}")]

bold part is dynamic. For example, if I use only English for user interface langage, I want to '**announcements**' instead of bolded part above. If I use English, Turkish and Spanish I want to '**announcements|duyurular|anuncios**'.

If I do like below, I get error because Attributes are accepts constant string variables:

```
[Route("{leftPath:values(" + GetRouteValues() + ")}/{announceUrl?}")]
public ActionResult Announcements(string leftPath, string announceUrl)
{
    ViewBag.Url = announceUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Is there any way to do this or any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry about this but I found my solution, I didn't try solutions enough.
This code is fixed my problem. (in RouteConfig class -> RegisterRoutes() function.):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "announcementRoute",
    url: "{leftPath}/{announcementUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Announces", announcementUrl = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { leftPath = new ValuesConstraint(Tools.GetRouteValues("announcements")) }
);
```

> constraints: new {
>   leftPath = new ValuesConstraint (**Tools.GetRouteValues ( "announcements" )**)
>   }

Bolded function returns string what i want: '**announcements**' or '**announcements|duyurular|anuncios**' based on language(s).

**For the curious:**

```
public class ValuesConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string[] validOptions;
    public ValuesConstraint(string options)
    {
        validOptions = options.Split('|');
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object value;
        if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
        {
            return validOptions.Contains(value.ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

more: [MSDN Resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)